# How to add custom permissions on GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE separately in function based view Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a project which has several user types  like Admin,coordinator,sub-coordinator and each user can work as a different role in different division.
Eg. user A can be a coordinator in DIVISION XX
then A can be a admin in DIVISION YY but he cannot have a same role in same division.

I am planning to write custom permissions and roles for this.
what I have written is something like this:

```
def coordinator(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    //some logic
    if request.method == 'POST':
    //some logic
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
    //some logic
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
    //some logic
```

what i **dont** want to do is the below approach:

```
def coordiantor_delete(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'DELETE':

def coordiantor_detail(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'GET':

def coordiantor_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

def coordiantor_update(request, uid):
    if request.method == 'PATCH':
```

Is there a way to add permissions to specific HTTP methods of a view function without splitting it in various views. Because I only want to have one API endpoint like /coordinator/ and /coordinator/id/
which should support above HTTP methods but with permissions like admin can also delete coordinator from a division and a coordinator himself can also leave a division and no one else has this authority over DELETE method.
Let me know what are the possible approaches to this or some other changes that needs to be made.

Comment: Are you sending the request in required format?  If yes, you should be able to do so as you require

Comment: @Abhyudai if by format you mean json then yes i am sending the request in proper format. Its not about the format ..its about how I will protect GET PUT PATCH inside the view itself. I know about decorators but I guess they can only be applied to a function and not  a if block

Comment: i mean to say the request format i.e GET or POST etc.

Comment: @Abhyudai how will I different permissions check on get and post method because coordinators are allowed to post but sub coordinators are not allowed...should use decorator if yes then how or something else like if else

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer to try to suit your needs better. This is not a complete solution, and I'd consider refactoring it and customize it to your needs.

I have two solutions in mind,

1. Create a decorator, accept a function to check for restrictions on certain methods, and raise PermissionDenied which invokes a 403 template.
2. Create a simple function that does some testing, and if the testing fails, raise PermissionDenied. Call this function inside each method in your view function.

I prefer method 1 because of the reusability of decorators.

Here's my initial setup

```
from functools import wraps

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.http import HttpResponse


def permission_denied_test(test_func):
    """
    Decorator for views that raises PermissionDenied if test_func fails
    The test should be a callable and returns True if the test is passed
    Your test function has access to the views request object
    """
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if test_func(request):
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            raise PermissionDenied
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator


def coordinator_passes_test(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return True  # passed test
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return False  # failed test


@permission_denied_test(coordinator_passes_test)
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse('Passed test, this code is reached.')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse('Failed test, this code isnt reached.')
```

This way your testing is reusable and you can easily apply it to multiple views

Comment: Hi viktor, can you please elaborate on your answer as to how will be the structure of PermissionDenied and how will I pass arguments to it.

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully it answers your question better